# Что значит "на стероидах"?

Tags: java, терминология

Что значит "на стероидах" в рамках программирования?

Например, что значит:

> AppBarLayout - это LinearLayout на стероидах

или:

> Closure in Groovy can be thought of as lambdas on steroids.
>   (Замыкание в Groovy можно рассматривать как лямбды на стероидах.)

Comment: то же самое, что и в повседневной жизни, когда это выражение используется в переносном смысле. То есть "улучшенная версия", "обладающий бОльшими возможностями". Никаких сугубо программистских смыслов тут нет

Comment: aka прокачанный

Comment: @DreamChild, в повседневном смысле у результатов, полученных *на стероидах*, возможна куча неприятных побочных эффектов. К приведенным в вопросе примерам это тоже относится?

Comment: Вопрос к программированию не относится, выражение может быть применено к чему угодно («Экономика КНР это коммунизм на стероидах», «Новый смартфон бюджетник на стероидах» и т.д.) Может на «[Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)» перенести?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что "на стероидах" относится не только к программированию. Вопрос следовало бы задать на филологическом форуме.

Answer (score 1):

Стероиды как вещество появились на земле еще в докембрийскую эпоху. Человек их начал получать только в конце 17- начале 18 века. Первое полученное вещество - холестерин (было получено из желчных камней). Активно стали изучаться с конца 19 века. Известность стероиды получили с 50-х годов 20 века - когда изобрели первый анаболический стероид - т.е. позволяющий ускорить рост мышечной ткани. Но применяющие их спортсмены столкнулись с проблемами со здоровьем. В настоящее время термин "на стероидах" применяется в значении "ускоренный", "разогнанный" - но иногда со "смысловым оттенком", который связан с ухудшением остальных характеристик.